# Get directly previous XML comment with XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, dom4j

I'm trying to detect whether an element has a comment directly preceding it.

I was using `preceding-sibling::comment()[last()]`, but that wouldn't be accurate in the case of the "B" element below:

```
<!-- Comment for A -->
<string name="A">A</string>
<string name="B">B</string>
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test="( preceding-sibling::* | preceding-sibling::comment() )[last()][self::comment()]"`

This takes the union of all preceding-sibling elements and comments, takes the last of them, and returns the last of them if it is a comment, and the test returns `true()` because the returned node set is non-empty.

Note that if I wasn't using the union operator, `preceding-sibling::comment()[1]` returns the closest because a predicate applied to a location step is in proximity order.  Your use of `[last()]` returns the farthest comment, not the closest comment.  In my test above the union is in document order (because it isn't a location step, it is the union of two location steps), not proximity order, so I have to use `[last()]` and not `[1]`.

Comment: This makes sense, but what would the syntax be to use it without the test? If the second part of it returns the last of the union if its a comment, that's all I'm interested in for my uses. (The XPath would be run from the context of the string element itself)

Comment: The expression doesn't change.  As I said, the way I wrote it returns the actual comment node to the test to make the node set non-empty, which tests as true.  So if you use that expression in a select, you get the comment node if it is the node addressed and you get the empty set if there is no such node.

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
preceding-sibling::node()[not(self::text()[not(normalize-space())])]
                         [1]
                         [self::comment()]
```

which finds the first preceding sibling node that is not a whitespace-only text node, and then returns it provided it is a comment.